# Leveraging FHE transpiler in Monero

Tags: cryptography

Google released recently [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) [source code for a "Fully Homomorphic Encryption Transpiler"](https://github.com/google/fully-homomorphic-encryption). [Here is the associated paper](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/bec910c4455e5f0464ce112678424dac729a4448.pdf).

How can this be leveraged for Monero ?

For example, can this be used to make the daemon fully ignorant of wallet's data ?